# How to pass a 2D array in C++ without knowing the dimensions

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, c++14

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int n;

int diagonal(int m[][n]){
    int r = 0,l = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        l += m[i][i];
        r += m[n-i][i];
    }
    if(r>l) return r - l;
    else return l - r;
}

int main(){
    cin >> n;
    int a[n][n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) for(int j=0;j<n;j++) cin >> a[i][j];
    cout << diagonal(a) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why I am getting errors running above code.

**Error No.1: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token**, how am I supposed to pass a constant value if I am taking it from the user.

**Error No.2: 'n' was not declared in this scope
6 |     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){**, no idea about this one.

Comment: You can switch to `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` which can be sized at runtime, and provides a `.size()` method to query the number of elements

Comment: `int a[n][n];` is invalid C++ (use VLA extension).

Comment: If you must use arrays, why not pass `n` as a separate argument? (Also, you don't declare `n` in `main`.)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: Whichever C++ textbook gave this example of passing `int m[][n]` as a function parameter -- this is not valid C++ so you should get a better C++ textbook and throw away this one.

Answer (score 2):

> `Error No.1: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token`,
> how am I supposed to pass a constant value if I am taking it from the user.

You can't. When you want to use variable length arrays, you should usually replace them with `std::vector`s.

Example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int diagonal(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& m) {
    int r = 0, l = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < m.size(); ++i) {
        l += m[i][i];
        // r += m[n - i][i]; //  m[n][0]` when `i == 0`.
        r += m[m.size() - i - 1][i];
    }

    // this is most likely implemented without branching:
    return std::abs(r - l);
}

int main() {
    // use an unsigned type suitable for indexing like size_t
    if(size_t n; std::cin >> n) {

        // int a[n][n];               // not valid C++

        // vector replacement:
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(n, std::vector<int>(n));

        for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                std::cin >> a[i][j];
            }
        }
        std::cout << diagonal(a) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using templates:

```
template<auto X, auto Y>
int diagonal(int (&m)[X][Y]){
```

Comment: I'd say `const int (&m)[Y][X]` but you still have to deal with `int a[n][n];` to make use of that function.

Comment: Why would you prefer Y before X?

Comment: Because multidimensional arrays are stored in [row-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) order in C++ - and the common usage is to have columns in the inner loop and rows in the outer loop.